# Error trying to install any macOS version in macbook 2010 mid

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, catalina

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve for weeks, and nowhere do I find a solution to this, perhaps someone with more knowledge will help me and help others with this thread, the problem is as follows

I have a 2010 macbook mid, and I had high sierra installed, I want to go to catalina, use the catalina patcher to perform the entire procedure exactly as indicated by others as well

> usb botteable utilize 2
> format use all
> Also try to install it without usb
> use OS image from internet downloaded via torrent or download it from the catalina patcher app itself
>
> use also mojave patcher and high sierra patcher

when entering the bootable formatie as apfs guid, and also use the mac os format
I have the same error
after starting the installer after 2 minutes it goes to a screen that shows the error

"MacOS cannot be installed on your computer"
an error occurred while installing macOS, to use apple diagnostics to check your mac's hardware, turn off the computer, etc, etc

To see the diagnostic error, it does not show anything, only the planet and an exclamation point, nor using the internet cable.

> I also changed the DATE to finish changing the date from 2016 to 2021 and I don't solve it

I think from my point of view that the error is in the image that is downloaded by OSX (although the downloaded megabytes seem the correct size), can it be that you have to use a virgin image? I do not know what to do, if someone can help in this it would be appreciated in a huge way

imagen for error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a 2010 MacBook, I have a 2010 iMac and Catalina nor Mojave will run on my machine. I think your machine is too old to install Catalina. You should check the [system requirements for Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210222). It doesn't list a 2010 MacBook as being compatible.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR format the disk as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and not as APFS before running the installer.

I had this error today on a 13" MacBook Air 2012 trying to install macOS Catalina 10.15.5. I first tried with Command+R and then with Command+Option+R. When this error appeared I used the menu to show the Log. I scrolled the log up until the line before it mentions the install failing and it said something like this:

`Clearing automation and attempting to rebless`

To me this looked like an APFS error, so I used disk utility to format the hard drive as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and then attempted the install again and it fixed this problem and the install worked. Because one stage of the installer is to convert the disk the resulting install was APFS despite starting as Mac OS Extended Journaled.

This was with an Internet recovery install so I suppose the downloaded install dmg cannot be extracted to an APFS volume yet and set as bootable, hopefully Apple fix that.

Answer (score 0):

[dosdude1.com/software.html](http://dosdude1.com/software.html) has a free OS patcher with simple instructions. It takes 30 minutes to a few hours depending on your machine. It will create a USB loader that can install any OS on unsupported Macs.

Just got my MacBook Pro mid-2009 running High Sierra like new, after 6 weeks of frustration trying to fresh install. You might need another Mac if your one is not booting.